# How to remove duplicate rows and aggregate corresponding values

Tags: bash, shell

I've a CSV with comma-separated values as a result of using JMeter's CMDRunner.jar for a performance test providing latency/request over a period of time.

```
2017/02/03 11:15:41.593,15,End-to-end request-response,15
2017/02/03 11:15:41.609,6,Request body is proxied successfully to the backend,6
2017/02/03 11:15:41.616,5,x-junction-path validator,5
2017/02/03 11:15:41.622,9,Invalid content type sent by client ,9
2017/02/03 11:15:41.634,3,Invalid content type requested by client ,3
2017/02/03 11:15:42.595,10,End-to-end request-response,10
2017/02/03 11:15:42.606,10,Request body is proxied successfully to the backend,10
2017/02/03 11:15:42.616,9,x-junction-path validator,9
2017/02/03 11:15:42.625,8,Invalid content type sent by client ,8
2017/02/03 11:15:42.635,5,Invalid content type requested by client ,4
2017/02/03 11:15:43.599,3,End-to-end request-response,3
2017/02/03 11:15:43.603,6,Request body is proxied successfully to the backend,6
2017/02/03 11:15:43.609,7,x-junction-path validator,7
2017/02/03 11:15:43.617,4,Invalid content type sent by client ,4
2017/02/03 11:15:43.622,7,Invalid content type requested by client ,7
```

I would like to aggregate the latencies per request which means a single entry per request and corresponding aggregate latencies ie. 3rd and 4th columns respectively. Is there a jmeter plugin to obtain this result or else how may I do this in BASH?

Expected output (eg.):

Note: Since this is an aggregate the timestamp and elapsedtime(2nd column) are irrelevant.

```
End-to-end request-response,12.31
equest body is proxied successfully to the backend,6.1
x-junction-path validator,5.0
Invalid content type sent by client, 3.12
Invalid content type requested by client ,3.01
```

Comment: Provide textual representation of the image, copy and paste it from console. to enable us to test. Also provide an expected output for the same

Comment: What is your exact expected output for the above input?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the description to with the textual representation and exp. o/p.

Comment: It's just an example, ie. average could be a float value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Awk` could help you with this,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{unique[$3]+=$4; count[$3]++;}END{for (i in unique) print i, unique[i]/count[i]}' file
x-junction-path validator,7
Invalid content type requested by client ,4.66667
Invalid content type sent by client ,7
Request body is proxied successfully to the backend,7.33333
End-to-end request-response,9.33333
```

Also possible with `printf` with `.2` degree precision on floating point arithmetic as

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{unique[$3]+=$4; count[$3]++;}END{for (i in unique) printf "%s,%0.2f\n", i, unique[i]/count[i]}' file
x-junction-path validator,7.00
Invalid content type requested by client ,4.67
Invalid content type sent by client ,7.00
Request body is proxied successfully to the backend,7.33
End-to-end request-response,9.33
```